# How can I create Master Detail Page using React

Tags: reactjs

How can I create Master / Detail using ReactJs. I have the following code which displays record from `Json` file but I need help on how to create a detail page using.

Comment: Can you please share your app code or sandbox code. I think something is missing up here as there is error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigation' of undefined" but navigation is nowhere in the above code.

Comment: @ShraddhaGoel  Thanks just a sec?

Comment: i never used codesandbox let me know if you have any issues with the link

Comment: seems like a missing data file.  Can you share your git code?

Comment: added sample data, can you please check. Thanks @Shraddha Goel

Comment: @ShraddhaGoel does that work?

Comment: yes it seems working. You need to put up the master file also where you are getting an error. In order to fix, I want the exact code where you getting error

Comment: @ShraddhaGoel that's the master file i was trying to get it to work by reading some article but i feel its not right way of doing it that why i didn't include it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203079/discussion-between-shraddha-goel-and-kuku).

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look this:

1.) If you haven't installed react-router-dom yet then, You must install react-router-dom using npm:

- npm install --save react-router-dom

2.) Import Route, Switch modules from react-router-dom and intialize the routes like as below:

```js
import { Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const Routes = ({ match }) => (
  <Switch>
    <Route path={`${match.url}/fetchdata`} component={FetchData} />
    <Route path={`${match.url}/employee/detail`} component={EmployeeDetail} />
  </Switch>
);
export default Routes;
```

3.) In FetchData component update as below:

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class FetchData extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={}
  }
  navigateToDetailPage = (empId) =>{
    const {history} = this.props;
    history.push('.employee/detail', { id: empId });
  }

  render(){
    return(
      <Button title="View detail" onPress={() => navigateToDetailPage(results.Employee_Number)} /> 

    );
  }
}
export default FetchData;
```

4.) In EmployeeDetail component you can get that data as below:

```js
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const EmployeeDetail = (props) => {
  const {  location } = props;
    const { id } = location.state;

}
export default withRouter(EmployeeDetail);
```

Comment: i get these error `'navigateToDetailPage' is not defined  no-undef`

Comment: because you haven't changed that with your onClick method name, You should change this with method name

Comment: Sorry Govind which onclick method?

Comment: navigateToDetailPage = (empId) =>{
    const {history} = this.props;
    history.push('.employee/detail', { id: empId });
  }

Comment: On your View detail button you have onPress={() => navigate('Details', {id:results.Employee_Number)} instead of this please replace this with onCline={() => navigateToDetailPage(results.Employee_Number)}

Comment: Do you have another JSON file for getting more information about the users?

Comment: Would you please share that one also and MasterPage too?

Comment: but there is no <Button title="View detail" onPress={() => navigate('Details', {id:results.Employee_Number)}    />

Answer (score 1):

```
<Route path='/Details' component={Details} />
```

So if u have defined the route then u can call the url by push method

```
onClick={() => this.props.history.push('/details')}
```